# Cygwin can't find the top command

Tags: command-line, cygwin

When I want to run `top` I get a message saying that the command cannot be found.

I had a similar problem with the nano text editor.

I resolved that by installing the nano package from the Cygwin installer a second time.

Is there a particular package I need to install for `top` as well?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a particular Cygwin package I need to install for `top`?

You need the `procps` package.

---

#### How can I find out which package `top` is in?

The easiest way to find the package containing a particular command or file is to use the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) page:

1. Open the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) web page in your web browser.

   > [image]
2. Select either the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Cygwin.
3. Enter the name of the program you are looking for (`top`).
4. Press "Go" on the web page.

In this case, entering just `top` matches many (2475) packages (for most commands there are fewer matches).

> [image]

So let's try entering the function of the command instead of its name:

3. Enter the function of the program you are look for (`process monitor`).
4. Press "Go" on the web page.

   > [image]

Now we have a more manageable list ( 8 matches) and we can easily see that the required package is probably:

> procps-3.2.8-5 - procps: System and process monitoring utilities (installed binaries and support files)

Click on [procps-3.2.8-5](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fprocps%2Fprocps-3.2.8-5&grep=process) to make sure we have the correct package and we can see:

> 2016-01-25 10:20       90643 usr/bin/top.exe
>
> [image]